# Jquery not allowing me to enter underscore

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi Guys i have this following code in jquery which is not allowing me to enter underscore.

```
$(".user-check").on("keydown", function(event){


// Allow controls such as backspace, tab etc.
  
  

switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 8:  // Backspace
    case 9:  // Tab
    case 13: // Enter
    case 16: // Shift
    case 37: // Left
    case 38: // Up
    case 39: // Right
    case 40: // Down
    case 189: // underscore
    break;
    default:
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$");
    var key = event.key;
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    break;
}
});
```

my goal is to allow alpha numeric characters and allow underscore. No other special characters

Thanks

Comment: "*it's not allowing an underscore [character]*" - *"my goal is alpha numeric only"* - note that a `_` character is **not** considered an "alpha numeric" character (0-9/a-z) - so what **exactly** do you want?

Comment: You're explicitly blocking the underscore before you get to your regex - change `case 189: // underscore` to `//case 189: // underscore`

Comment: sorry just updated the question. I need alpha numeric characters and underscore only no other special characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is little unclear but if you want to just allow user to enter alphanumeric characters with underscore, try using this code:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$");
var key = event.key;
if (!regex.test(key)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Also, you can avoid switch and remove the `case:` part

Comment: but it will allow special character as well which i dont want

Answer (score 0):

This is only allow alpha-numeric characters only

```js
    $(".user-check").keydown(function (e){
        var k = e.keyCode || e.which;
        var ok = k >= 65 && k <= 90 || // A-Z
            k >= 96 && k <= 105 || // a-z
            k >= 35 && k <= 40 || // arrows
            k == 9 || //tab
            k == 189 || //Underscore 
            k == 46 || //del
            k == 8 || // backspaces
            (!e.shiftKey && k >= 48 && k <= 57); // only 0-9 (ignore SHIFT options)

        if(!ok || (e.ctrlKey && e.altKey)){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="user-check" name="username">
```

Comment: i want to allow alpha numeric input along with underscore only. Not any other special character

Comment: I have edited my answer code segment and now it will be allow alpha numeric input along with underscore only.

Comment: tried but still not working not taking undersocre.